# Problem downloading plugin in eclipse helios 2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

I am having problem in downloading my plug-in in eclipse helios2. the update site is: http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/install.htm. It worked fine up to helios1.

This is the error I get :

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,fastcodefeature,1.0.0.201012110203.
Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server.

**Edit**: here is my site.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/fastcodefeature_1.2.0.jar" id="fastcodefeature" version="1.2.0">
  <category name="FastCode"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="FastCode" label="FastCode">
   <description>
     Fast Code Eclipse Plugin
  </description>
   </category-def>
</site>
```

now where it is getting the featured version: org.eclipse.update.feature,fastcodefeature,1.0.0.201012110203?

Comment: Have you tried installation from local update site? Or perhaps installing some of the previous versions?

Answer (score 2):

See "Downloaded stream not a valid archive. Check the server." May be archive isn't valid?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your fastcodefeature_1.2.0.jar file is not a valid feature jar.  It does not contain a MANIFEST.MF file.  I would recommend rebuilding your feature (and associated plugins).  File -> Export -> Deployable features should do the trick.